# Is it possible to output a .csv from Tableau Prep using the pipe-delimiter rather than default comma-delimiter?

Tags: tableau-api

I cannot imagine that Tableau Prep supports only the comma as a delimiter.
I cannot figure out where to override it.  Am using Tableau Prep Builder 2020.1.2
Thank you. Prefer using the pipe character, for obvious reason.  Friends don't let friends use commas.

Comment: In the meantime, you can always use the linux/Unix tr command to translate commas into pipes. Or awk if you want to leave quoted commas as is. Annoying to need an extra step, but super easy

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently available as an option but is being requested by the community. You can vote for it here: https://community.tableau.com/ideas/8697